# Как обращаться к лэйблам во второй форме в цикле?

Tags: delphi-7

```
for j:=1 to 3 do
begin
  form2.TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+IntToStr(i))).Caption := a[i,j];
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Переставьте приведение типа, оно у вас не на месте:

```
TLabel(form2.FindComponent('Label'+IntToStr(i))).Caption := a[i,j];
```